# Paypal Authorize and Capture with partial refund and avoid

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

1) Buyer purchase a product from seller and authroize from PayPal

2) Due to XYZ reason buyer cancel partial order

3) Now, seller need to capture a partial amount and void remaining amount

I have perform following action in PayPal

1) Authorize API using following API : (300$ of authroize)

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create

intent : authroize

2) Capture a partial amount (Lesser amount than authroize - 200$ of capture)

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#capture

amount : 200

So I want to do 200$ capture and 100$ return to buyer

Now which API need to use to release remaining authroize funds to buyer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to return or refund for an authorization.

If you do a partial capture on an authorization the rest of the authorization $100  should just drop off.

For eg if the buyer used credit card with a remaining credit balance of $1000 and you authorized they will see a pending transaction for $300 ( available credit drops to $700) - once you capture $200 the available credit should jump to ($800)

Are the buyers complaining that this isn’t the case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can void the authorization after the partial capture is done to instantly release the hold funds. If the authorization is not voided, the funds should be released after 3 days from the time of authorization.

Refer [here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_void) for the API details.